# jQuery Content Slider with Unique Animated Panels

Tags: jquery, animation, slider, slideshow, jquery-animate

I'm looking for a jQuery content slider that will allow me to animate the content on each slide, and do unique animations between slides that I can control (not random).

Basically, each slide will have 3 elements. A picture, a rectangular background color shape, and some text. On each slide, I want each of the elements to move into the screen (bg slides in, then pic on top, then text on top of that. For each slide, I want the animation to come from a different direction (text from top on the first one, from the right on the second) and so on.
I would also like the transitions between slide to be controlled (on the first slide transition, use a fade, on the second use a slide in from top, etc)

I thought I had seen a plugin like this awhile ago (maybe on smashing magazine?) but can't seem to find it.
Anyone know of anything like this I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This slider](http://www.onebyoneslider.com/) can be used for creating custom animations for each content part using data attributes. Animations are driven by [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) and background transitions by JQuery, so you can easily change them.

There are also many cool examples at Codecanyon, I think [this one](http://codecanyon.net/item/parallax-slider-responsive-jquery-plugin/3217681?ref=korolov) is the best